# Run facebook pixel with rails and turbolinks

Tags: javascript, turbolinks, facebook-pixel

The Facebook pixel's initialization code and PageView code is recommended to be placed inside the  section:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-pixel/using-the-pixel#get

The problem is that the head of the webpage is never reloaded with Rails turbolinks. Pixel does send a pageView event to Facebook on pushState/popState, but with the wrong URL - the URL from the initial loading of the page. I'm assuming that pixel saves the initial location 
(when the fbq('init') is called) and then reuses it for the PageView event.

I tried to put the entire code segment in the body, but the result was "Facebook Pixel Error: Duplicate Pixel ID: XXXXXXXXXX" java script error.

I tried to split the code and put the fbq('init', XXXXX) event in the head and then on page:change event to call fbq('track', 'PageView');
But the problem is that this once again uses the initial URL.

I also tried to set the window.fbq variable to undefined and call again init before PageView - all of this in the page:change callback.
But then I got the "Facebook Pixel Warning: Multiple pixels with conflicting versions were detected on this page" and again the PageView was called with the wrong url.

Has anyone ever made Facebook pixel work with turbolinks?

Answer (score 7):

I'm using the following JS that gets loaded in the head:

```
/* insert pixel load function here */

function trackPageView() {
  fbq('init', 'PIXEL_ID')
  fbq('track', 'PageView')
}

document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', trackPageView, true)
```

When I test it locally with the Facebook Pixel Helper it shows a PageView event on each page I navigate to with turbolinks, and no warnings.